# Open NetBeans Java project into IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea, ide

I've got a project written in `Java` language, i made it in **NetBeans IDE**, but now i want to migrate to **IntelliJ IDEA**, the problem is that when i try to open a form into IntelliJ GUI Designer i can't edit my forms, IntelliJ tells me that it's not compatible.

[This post](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/IntelliJ+IDEA+for+NetBeans+Users#IntelliJIDEAforNetBeansUsers-HowcanIopenaNetBeansprojectinIntelliJIDEA%3F) says that:

> Currently there is no "Import NetBeans project" functionality in IntelliJ IDEA. However, in IntelliJ IDEA you can create a new project with existing sources. So in many cases moving the project to IDEA is not a complex operation, you can create a new project from existing sources using the "File | New Project" action. You can ask IntelliJ IDEA to use the same directory as your NetBeans project is using. IntelliJ IDEA then adds .iml file (idea module file) and .idea configuration directory. The NetBeans .nbproject directory and build.xml remain untouched, so you can continue using IntelliJ IDEA along with NetBeans.

But if i add the sources of my project to IDEA project i can't open my forms.

I've searched and found that using **`JFormDesigner`** would be an option, but i would like to know if there's another way, if not how would i use JFormDesigner?

Comment: I was at the interview last week, and I asked the person why do not you use Netbeans? He said that it is not as generic as eclipse. I thought it is good to share this with you :)

Comment: IMO the best way to make your project working in many different Java IDEs is to use Maven -- Eclipse, Netbeans and IDEA can open Maven projects. For `JFormDesigner`, they provide plugins for both Netbeans and IDEA. However, you can also write your GUI directly from java code using Swing.

Comment: @KickButtowski thanks, and i think that's why i'm moving to IntelliJ

Comment: @coolcfan But what can i do if i've already created my java app without using maven?

Comment: @JonathanSolorzano It depends. Maven is a "convention over configuration" tool. If your project is simple and clean, then just create a maven project, put your java code into "src/main/java", and add dependencies in `pom.xml`.

Comment: what u mean by simple and clean? @coolcfan

Comment: @JonathanSolorzano e.g. you don't need to specify dependency that can't be found in any online repository; you don't need to call any external commands when building your project from Ant; all your files can be put into maven project's directories without any modification... Try start doing it, and search or ask for help when you encounter problems.

Comment: Sounds like your main requirement is a netbeans to JFormDesigner converter. Once in that format, the build process should run smoothly, whether with maven or not.

Comment: @coolcfan so that you mean that if i make my project in maven then the forms created on NetBeans IDE will be readable on IntelliJ?

Comment: @vikingsteve No, my main requirement is open a form created in NetBeans on IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: I fear your only choice is to redesign the forms in IntelliJ Form Designer. Would this be much work? Since translating GUI designs to code is generally a one-way process...